# Update/refresh edited PostGIS table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I imported a PostGIS table (with geometry) from my PostgreSQL database as a layer in QGIS.
Later, I edited the table using PostgreSQL `UPDATE` commands.

Is there a way to quickly update (like a **refresh ↻** command?) the layer in QGIS with the new attributes or geometry without having to remove the layer and reconnect with the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all you need to do is zoom in or out in your map canvas.

<s>You can also uncheck and check again the render checkbox in the right left corner.</s>

Regarding the attribute table you might have to close it and open it again.

Comment: Does this actually work for you? Because it doesn't seem to make a difference for me.

Comment: Sorry, the render does not work. But the Zoom in and out does.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it seems to work consistently now, but I could have sworn this didn't work earlier. I opened and closed the attribute table several times before posting the question. Weird. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note that it's the same for sql server tables.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that (re)sorting the field (by clicking the field name header at the top) will force the attribute table to refresh with the new values. This also works if you're editing directly in QGIS.

You can get the map data to update either by zooming or just a quick nudge/pan with the mouse, or by hitting the refresh button.